# Pullback of $S^n$ volume form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, hodge-theory

I am working on problems from Nakahara's book Geometry, Topology and Physics and I am struggling with exercise 9.2

> Let $\Omega_n$ be the volume form of $S^n$ normalized to 1, $f:S^{2n-1}\to S^n$ be a smooth map and denote by $f^*\Omega_n$ the pullback of $\Omega_n$ to $S^{2n-1}$.
> (a) Show that $f^*\Omega_n$ is closed and written as $d\omega_{n-1}$ where $\omega_{n-1}$ is an $(n-1)$-form on $S^{2n-1}$.

I showed that $\Omega_n$ is closed, since $df^*\Omega_n=f^*d\Omega_n$ and $\Omega_n$ is a top form in $S^n$. I cannot show that $f^*\Omega_n$ is exact though. Indeed, I would tend to think that it is not. This is my argument.\

By Hodge's decomposition, I can write
\begin{equation}
\Omega_n=d\alpha_{n-1}+\gamma_n
\end{equation}
where $\gamma_n$ is harmonic ($\Delta \gamma_n=0$). The pullback of $\Omega_n$ is thus
\begin{equation}
f^*\Omega_n=f^*d\alpha_{n-1}+f^*\gamma_n=df^*\alpha_{n-1}+f^*\gamma_n
\end{equation}
Now, by the uniqueness of the decomposition, if $f^*\Omega_n$ were to be exact, I should have $f^*\alpha_{n-1}=\omega_{n-1}$ and $f^*\gamma_n=0$.
However, $\gamma_n$ is different from $0$ as $\Omega_n$ is not exact, so $f^*\gamma_n\ne 0$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You can compute the de Rham cohomology of $S^{2n-1}$ explicitly. Are there any non-trivial cycles in degree $n$?

Comment: Why is the Hodge decomposition of $f^*\Omega_n$ the pullback of the Hodge decomposition of $\Omega_n$? Note that the Hodge decomposition depends on a choice of metric.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, I think that it is so because the decomposition is unique

Comment: The pullback of a harmonic form by an arbitrary smooth map has no reason whatsoever to be harmonic again.

Comment: @GiulioNeri: After you pick a metric, it is unique. But if you change the metric, you might get a different decomposition.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I guess I was recklessly assuming $f^* \delta=\delta f^*$ where $\delta$ is the adjoint of $d$. I will follow @PedroTamaroff's suggestion.